# qtpropertybrowser slowness

Tags: c++, qt

I've noticed that [qtpropertybrowser](http://doc.trolltech.com/solutions/4/qtpropertybrowser/index.html) can be rather slow for large numbers of properties. Can someone recommend ways to speed it up, or perhaps a better alternative for use with QT applications? I have seen this: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/5490 however, the fix described there doesn't seem to speed things up drastically.

Thanks!